# Why does this sequence not have a limit? $(C_n)_{n\in N}\ with \ c_n = (-1)^n\frac{n^3 + 2}{n^2+1}$ for all $n \in N$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does this sequence not have a limit?

$(C_n)_{n\in N}\  with \ c_n = (-1)^n\frac{n^3 + 2}{n^2+1}$ for all $n \in N$

There sadly isn't any explanation for this particular sequence in my text book, it just says that it has no upper, or lower limit. I understand that the $(-1)^n$ means that the respective element is positive whenever n is even and negative whenever n is uneven, but couldn't it still have a minimum in the negative numbers and a maximum in the positive numbers?

Comment: Ignore the $(-1)^n$. That just means the terms oscilate.  But notice $\frac {n^3 + 2 }{n^2 + 1} \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\frac {n^3 + 2}{n^2 + 1} = \frac {n^3 + n^2 - n^2 -1 + 3}{n^2 + 1} = n -1 + \frac 3{n^2 + 1}$

For any $N$ then for any even $n > |N| + 1$ then $c_n > |N|$.  and for any odd $n > N + 1$ then $c_n < -|N|$.

So like the text says, there is no upper or lower limit.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using a ratio test to show this?

Comment: No, I am not.  I am showing it directly be the definition of limits.  $c_n > n-1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!